# Javascript odd StackOverflow error

Tags: javascript, error-handling, stack, stack-overflow

I was wondering about the working of parentheses in Javascript, so I wrote this code to test:

```
((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
4+4
))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Which consists in:

```
( x1174
4+4
) x1174
```

I tested the code above on Google Chrome 20 (Win64), and it gives me the right answer (`8`).

But if I try the same code, but with 1175 parentheses (on both sides), I get a **stackoverflow** error.

You can check this code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2tx4G/) (Note: in JSFiddle it stops working with 1178 parentheses)

So, my questions are:

- Why does it happen?
- Why does it stop working with 1178 parentheses on JSFiddle but with only 1175 on my blank page?
- Does this error depend of the page/browser/os?

Comment: What is this test for? Any applications?

Comment: Just for curiosity. No significative applications

Comment: Btw, according to the (ECMAScript) standard, there is no limit (since the [*PrimaryExpression*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1) production is recursive).

Comment: I've tried your demo in Firefox. It throws "too much recursion". I'm not sure why this is a stack overflow error in Chrome (what have nested parens to do with the stack?)...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I think "too much recursion" and "stack overflow" are pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Often languages are parsed by code designed along a pattern called **recursive descent**. I don't know for sure that that's the case here, but certainly the "stack overflow" error is a big piece of evidence.

The idea is that to parse an expression, you approach the syntax by looking at what an expression can be. A *parenthesized* expression is like an "expression within an expression".  Thus, for a parser to systematically parse some expression in code it's seeing for the first time (which, for a parser, is its eternal fate), a left parenthesis means "ok - hold on to what you're doing (on the stack), and go start from the beginning of what an expression can possibly be and parse a fresh, complete expression, and come back when you see the matching close paren".

Thus, a string of a thousand or more parenthesis triggers an equivalent cascade of that same activity: put what we've got on a shelf; dive in and get a sub-expression, and then resume when we know what it looks like.

Now this is not the only way to parse something, it should be noted. There are many ways. I personally am a huge fan of recursive descent parsing, but there's nothing particularly special about it (except that I think it'll someday result in me seeing a real unicorn).

Answer (score 5):

The behavior is different in different browsers because they have different implementations of Javascript.  The language doesn't specify how something like this should fail, so each implementation fails in a different way.

The difference between JSFiddle and your blank page is because JSFiddle itself uses a few stack frames to establish the environment in which to run your code.

Comment: But why would parens increase the stack size? I thought only function invocations do that...

Comment: Who knows how the interpreter is written?  You may not be talking about the Javascript stack, but a C stack.  The internals of language implementations can get much more baroque than you'd imagine.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas see my answer :-) It's the **parsing** of the expression that causes the problem, not the evaluation.